# Listing filenames and timestamps in subdirectories recursively in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix, command-line

The command that I've been using is "ls -lR". The results usually look like this:

```
.:                                                                              
total 4                                                                         
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             9 Oct 11 03:35 dos -> /root/dos       
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            80 Oct 11 03:35 folder1                
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root           100 Oct 11 03:35 folder2                
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           242 Oct 11 03:35 hello.c                

./folder1:                                                                      
total 0                                                                         
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Oct 11 03:25 file1001               
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Oct 11 03:35 file1002               

./folder2:                                                                      
total 0                                                                         
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Oct 11 03:39 file2001                   
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Oct 11 03:45 file2002
```

How do I optimize the command so that it would only display the following?

```
./folder1:                                                                      
  Oct 11 03:25 | file1001               
  Oct 11 03:35 | file1002               

./folder2:                                                                                                                                              
  Oct 11 03:39 | file2001                   
  Oct 11 03:45 | file2002
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that might work:

```
~/mydir ls -lR | grep -vi "total" | egrep -o "^\.\/.*|^\..*|([A-Z])\w+\s+[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+\s+.*"
.:
Sep  4  2015 es_jira.py
Sep  4  2015 es_slurp_jira.py
Aug 21  2015 __init__.py
./plugins:
Sep  4  2015 __init__.py
Sep  4  2015 lrt_report.py
Sep 11  2015 mr_fingerprint.py
Mar  6  2016 mr_tunable.py
Dec  1  2015 plugin.py
Dec  1  2015 test
Dec  1  2015 utils.py
./plugins/test:
Sep  4  2015 _test_ca_space_plugin.py
Sep  4  2015 _test_lrt_report_plugin.py
Sep  4  2015 _test_mr_failover_plugin.py
Sep  4  2015 _test_mr_fingerprint_plugin.py
Dec  1  2015 _test_mr_tunable_plugin.py
Sep  4  2015 _test_spacedays_plugin.py
```

If you want to start adding tabs for nested lines and stuff, you're looking for a script and variable work, which is doable in a one-liner, but gets more complicated than a quick and dirty grep.

Comment: Is it possible to add a delimiter (e.g. |) between the timestamp and the filename? Also, I would also like to exclude the files in the root folder (i.e. only show the contents of the subfolders. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but you'll want to look into sed/awk for that - both can do the delimiter, and sed can get you only things in folders after the root folder, but that's a much longer tutorial than I can explain in a comment, and the syntax is a pain in the butt.